# Превращение одной БД в другую

Tags: java, база-данных, postgresql, access, jdbc

Есть готовая БД Access, задача состоит в том, чтоб взять ее и средствами java перевести в postgreSQL!

При этом нужно чтоб программа сама автоматично создавала таблицы аналогичные исходной БД и переносила данные!

**Вопрос:** возможно ли это ?
И с чего можно начать реализацию ?

Comment: Это разовая задача (миграция БД на другую платформу) или речь идёт о периодическом импорте из Access?

Comment: @Streletz, желательно чтоб все было автоматично независимо от структуры таблиц и их количества(это в идеале)! Конвертация будет периодической!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В принципе, данную задачу решить возможно. При этом я вижу 2 пути.

### 1й путь (через Java)

- Наладить соединение с Access. Например, при помощи JDBC-ODBC Bridge;
- Прочитать структуру таблиц;
- Создать аналогичные таблицы с аналогичной структурой в PostgreSQL;
- Скопировать данные из Access.

Путь крайне сложный, особенно, учитывая, что Java не очень хорошо поддерживает работу с определёнными инструментами Windows.

### 2й путь (средствами Access)

Access прекрасно поддерживает работу с ODBC. Это позволяет полностью экспортировать любую БД с помощью графического интерфейса Access. Затраты труда и времени при этом таковы, что, ИМХО, нет смысла писать отдельную программу.

Как-то так...

Comment: 1 путь - будет что в портфолио прикрепить!!!
Интересует как сделать аналогичную структуру заранее не зная какая бд будит конвертироваться!!!